# Implicit policy evaluation failed when creating a new channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am running a custom Hyperledger Fabric network over Kubernetes and now I am trying to automate the creation and joining of channels. The error I am getting right now is related to the creation of the channel itself.

The order I am following, related to the creation of the channels, is the following one (the example channel is named global):

1. Create `genesis.block` using `configtx.yaml`:

```sh
configtxgen -profile OrgsOrdererGenesis -configPath /data/config -outputBlock /data/genesis.block --channelID orderersglobal
```

1. Create `channel.tx` using the previously created `genesis.block`:

```sh
configtxgen -profile OrgsChannel -configPath /data/config -outputCreateChannelTx /data/global.tx -channelID global
```

1. Copy the `channel.tx` to each CLI and org
2. On each CLI, I enroll as admin and run the following command to create the channel block:

```sh
peer channel create -o orderer0.org1:7050 --channelID global -f /data/global.tx
```

However, I get this error:

```
2019-10-08 12:25:51.089 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'global', could not successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

As a consequence, I can not continue testing the network. I initially used the same `channelID` for `genesis.block` and `channel.block`, but I have changed it. I have read some posts about this but nothing seems to solve my problem. I hope some of you can help me.

---

This is my network architecture  (I am not using TLS)

- org1

  - peer0 (*anchor*)
  - peer1
  - orderer0
- org2

  - peer0 (*anchor*)
  - peer1
  - orderer0
- org3

  - orderer0

---

This is the content of my `configtx.yaml` file:

```
Capabilities:
  Global: &ChannelCapabilities
    V1_3: true
  Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V1_1: true
  Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V1_3: true
Organizations:
- &org1
  Name: org1
  ID: org1MSP
  MSPDir: /data/orgs/org1/msp
  AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org1MSP.member')"
    Writers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org1MSP.member')"
    Admins:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org1MSP.admin')"
  AnchorPeers:
    - Host: peer0.org1
      Port: 7051
- &org2
  Name: org2
  ID: org2MSP
  MSPDir: /data/orgs/org2/msp
  AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org2MSP.member')"
    Writers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org2MSP.member')"
    Admins:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org2MSP.admin')"
  AnchorPeers:
    - Host: peer0.org2
      Port: 7051
- &org3
  Name: org3
  ID: org3MSP
  MSPDir: /data/orgs/org3/msp
  AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org3MSP.member')"
    Writers:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org3MSP.member')"
    Admins:
      Type: Signature
      Rule: "OR('org3MSP.admin')"
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: kafka
  Addresses:
    - orderer0.org1:7050
    - orderer0.org2:7050
    - orderer0.org3:7050
  BatchTimeout: 2s
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 10
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
  MaxChannels: 0
  Kafka:
    Brokers:
      - bootstrap.kafka:9092
  Organizations:
      - *org1
      - *org2
      - *org3
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *OrdererCapabilities
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  ACLs: &ACLsDefault
    lscc/ChaincodeExists: /Channel/Application/Readers
    lscc/GetDeploymentSpec: /Channel/Application/Readers
    lscc/GetChaincodeData: /Channel/Application/Readers
    lscc/GetInstantiatedChaincodes: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetChainInfo: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetBlockByHash: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetTransactionByID: /Channel/Application/Readers
    qscc/GetBlockByTxID: /Channel/Application/Readers
    cscc/GetConfigBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
    cscc/GetConfigTree: /Channel/Application/Readers
    cscc/SimulateConfigTreeUpdate: /Channel/Application/Readers
    peer/Propose: /Channel/Application/Writers
    peer/ChaincodeToChaincode: /Channel/Application/Readers
    event/Block: /Channel/Application/Readers
    event/FilteredBlock: /Channel/Application/Readers
  Organizations:
  Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Profiles:
  OrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
      - *org1
      - *org2
      - *org3
      Capabilities:
        <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
      - *org1
      - *org2
      - *org3
      Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    Consortiums:
      SampleConsortium:
        Organizations:
        - *org1
        - *org2
  OrgsChannel:
    Capabilities:
      <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
      - *org1
      - *org2
      Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Comment: is your CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH set to admin msp of org ?

Comment: It is set to admin msp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most possible thing that is happening is: The certificate you are trying to use as a admin is not really an admin. Things you can check and see where you got it wrong:

- In the MSP folder you used for configtx.yaml (/data/orgs/org1/msp and /data/orgs/org2/msp) this folder is a folder on your computer (actually the computer/container that is running the configtxgen command), the first thing you have to check is if the folder is being created correctly.
- Is there a certificate on `admincerts` folder inside the MSP folder? If you do not have it, then the MSP does not have a admin.
- Another thing to be kept in mind is to use the persistent volume to "pass" the certificates generated either by the Fabric CA, cryptogen or any other CA
- I know for a fact that the MSPDir works with a relative path to configtx.yaml. I do not know if it works using the absolute path you are using.

Another thing you can do to check which certificate is being used for each MSP is to fetch the last config block `peer channel fetch config` and `configtxlator proto_decode --input <channel name>_config.block --type common.Block --output config.json` and then checking this JSON file

Comment: What I do is creating the MSP folder when an org is initialized and then I share it to a 'genesis' container where I generate the channel block, according to the cryptogen. It is possible, because of concurrence, that MSP folder is shared before admins are registered, as I only check that folder exists. I think it can be the problem. I will report.

Comment: However, does not include the MSP folder, specially admincerts, private data? Why has it to be shared to a common point to run the network? I have never understood it.

Comment: I resolved the concurrency problem and now I moved to this error: `[channel: global] Rejecting broadcast of message from 172.17.0.10:50180 with SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: rejected by Consenter: backing Kafka cluster has not completed booting; try again later`. Does it mean that I have advanced or is it another problem not related?

Comment: Well the problem with Kafka is already solved and now it seems like it is working, so it is solved. Thank you very much.